# Seeking compilers, any idea?

Tags: sql, c, compiler-construction, oracle10g

This semester, I'm learning database using the isql*plus (oracle10g), but that needs to install a server on the pc first so it will function well. That really lags my pc, and I just need to write simple code snippets, and view the output.

I've searched the internet for the isql*plus, found something called (altova database), but needs money.

Searched again for a C compiler, but found an old compiler (that's fine by me!) and found the dll libraries for the openGL, but don't know how to bind the library with that lousy compiler program I'm using; maybe a C compiler suitable for game programming is the best.

And I've been starving to find a C programming language compiler (World Widely Known), with the suitable OpenGL dll libraries.

Comment: I don't get it, are you looking for an Oracle IDE, or a C compiler?  I don't see how the two are related?

Comment: "found an old compiler ..., but don't know how to bind the library with that lousy compiler program" - maybe let us know what compiler you're talking about.

Comment: What are you looking for? You keep going back and forth between wanting a C compiler, and this isql-plus thing. If you want a C compiler, tell us what operating system you use. For OpenGL (where did that come from?), your system should either already have the libraries or you will need to install a development kit - tell us what you're looking for and what your operating system is.

Comment: I'm looking for an Oracle compiler and a C compiler.
I need both in this semester.
Hope that cleared up the ambiguity.

Comment: the lousy compiler of C's name is called "lcc"
 and it just looks like an old notepad application.

Comment: I need both compilers suitable for Windows

Comment: What do you mean by 'Oracle compiler'?

Comment: For Windows -> [Visual C++ 2010 with IDE](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) (C++ compiler, doesn't support C99), or [MingW GCC](http://www.mingw.org/) (has both C and C++ compilers).

Comment: @Obzajd - What, exactly, is an "Oracle compiler"?  SQL--and therefore any dialect thereof--is not a compiled language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to have Oracle, then check with your school to see if they've got a test Oracle server setup for students to use. If not, then get together with some friends in the same class and dedicate one machine to be your shared Oracle server. Alternately, just spin up the Oracle instance on your local box when you need it, and spin it back down when you don't.

If you are just learning SQL, then try something lighter like [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Both are free and much less resource intensive than Oracle. From a student perspective, the SQL language is similar enough. When you get into big applications and database administration, the differences between the different flavors of SQL servers becomes more important.

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is your go-to C/C++ compiler. Whether there is OpenGL support for it depends on the platform you are using. I can't tell if Visual Studio is free for students or not, but there is a 90-day free trial. That should be more than sufficient for a semester's worth of coding.

Comment: What a Powerful ANSWER! Very Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 2):

> This semester, I'm learning database using the isql*plus (oracle10g),
>   but that needs to install a server on the pc first so it will function
>   well.

Every version of Oracle you install locally will need to install a server to function at all, not just to function well.

> And I've been starving to find a C programming language compiler
>   (World Widely Known), with the suitable OpenGL dll libraries.

[iSQLPlus](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ISQLPlus) is a web-based utility that you can use to a) connect to a server, not necessarily running on your local PC, and b) enter SQL statements to be run on that server. It's not a compiler in any sense of the word. Whether you can connect to an instance of Oracle running on a different computer depends on a lot of TCP/IP and database security settings.

As a rule of thumb, it's pretty odd to *need* a C compiler when your goal is learning any SQL database, including Oracle.